# Getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Exception

Tags: java, jpa

I am getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` while running following code,

```
public class JPAUtil {

    private static final EntityManagerFactory emFactory;

    static {
        try {
            emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("org.hibernate.events");
        }catch(Throwable ex){
            System.err.println("Cannot create EntityManagerFactory.");
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static EntityManager createEntityManager() {
        return emFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public static void close(){
        emFactory.close();
    }
}
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
Cannot create EntityManagerFactory.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at util.JPAUtil.<clinit>(JPAUtil.java:16)
    at event.EventManager.createAndStoreEvent(EventManager.java:30)
    at event.EventManager.main(EventManager.java:18)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named org.hibernate.events
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:69)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at util.JPAUtil.<clinit>(JPAUtil.java:13)
    ... 2 more
```

Please help me & tell me where i am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("org.hibernate.events");
```

Right syntax:

```
emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("org.hibernate.events.jpa");
```

Comment: so you changed the persistence unit name despite the fact that the OP didn't say what persistence-units were present in their persistence.xml?