# happening " java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError " Caused by " Unable to build EntityManagerFactory " in JPA project

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, model-view-controller

I want create a web application and use JPA for model layer in MVC for the first time . But I'm having trouble. 
The program shows me this error :

```
Nov 11, 2018 10:56:49 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
Nov 11, 2018 10:56:49 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.0.Final}
Nov 11, 2018 10:56:49 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties:  {hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.h2.Driver, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect, hibernate.max_fetch_depth=5, hibernate.format_sql=true, hibernate.generate_statistics=true, hibernate.connection.username=sa, hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true, hibernate.connection.pool_size=5}
Nov 11, 2018 10:56:49 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at model.bl.PersonManager.main(PersonManager.java:19)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: MyConnection] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:930)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
at util.JPAProvider.<clinit>(JPAProvider.java:13)
... 6 more

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: UID in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(USERS) and its related supertables and secondary tables
at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:552)
at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:257)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1331)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindOneToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:791)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:719)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:668)
at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:66)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1593)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1350)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:920)
... 11 more
```

Person class :

```
package model.entity;
import model.bl.PersonManager;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

//mapping class to table
@Entity (name = "person")
@Table(name = "USERS")
@EntityListeners(value = PersonManager.class)

public class Person implements Serializable
{

@Id // create id and fill auto by sequence in database
@Column(name="UID" ,columnDefinition = "NUMBER" )
@SequenceGenerator(name = "mySeq" , sequenceName = "DB_MYSEQ")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO ,generator="mySeq")
private long uId;


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "FK_PERSON",referencedColumnName = "UID")
private List<Pictures> picturesList;


@Basic
@Column (name = "USERNAME" , columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR2(30)" , nullable = false , unique = true)
private String username ;

@Basic
@Column (name = "USER_PASSWORD" , columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR2(32)" , nullable = false , unique = true)
private String  password ;

@Basic
@Column (name = "EMAIL" , columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR2(40)" , nullable = false)
private String email;


@Basic
@Column (name = "SEX" , columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR2(20)")
private String sex ;

//--------------------------------------------------------

public Person() { }

public Person(String username, String password, String email, String sex, String userPic) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
    this.sex = sex;
    this.userPic = userPic;
}
public Person(String username, String password, String email ,String sex, String userPic,List<Pictures> picturesList ) {
    this.picturesList = picturesList;
    this.sex = sex;
    this.userPic = userPic;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.username = username;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public void setUserPic(String userPic) {
    this.userPic = userPic;
}

public void setSex(String sex) {
    this.sex = sex;
}

public void setuId(long uId) {this.uId = uId;}

//--------------------------------------------------------

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public String getUserPic() {
    return userPic;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getSex() {
    return sex;
}

public long getuId() {return uId;}

}
}
```

Pictures class :

```
package model.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity(name = "picture")
@Table(name = "PICTURE")

public class Pictures implements Serializable
{
@Id // create id and fill auto by sequence in database
@Column(name="PID" ,columnDefinition = "NUMBER" )
@SequenceGenerator(name = "mySeq2" , sequenceName = "DB_MYSEQ2")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO ,generator="mySeq2")
private long pId;


@Basic
@Column (name = "PICADRESS" , columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR2(50)" , nullable = false)
private String  picAdress ;

@Basic
@Column (name = "CAPTION" , columnDefinition = "LONG")
private String caption;

@Basic // user picture for profile
@Column (name = "LIKES" , columnDefinition = "NUMBER")
private int likes;

//--------------------------------------------------------
public Pictures(){}

public Pictures( String picAdress, String caption, int likes) {
    this.picAdress = picAdress;
    this.caption = caption;
    this.likes = likes;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------

public void setPid(long pid) {
    this.pId = pid;
}

public void setLikes(int likes) {
    this.likes = likes;
}

public void setPicAdress(String picAdress) {
    this.picAdress = picAdress;
}

public void setCaption(String caption) {
    this.caption = caption;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------

public int getLikes() {
    return likes;
}

public String getCaption() {
    return caption;
}

public String getPicAdress() {
    return picAdress;
}

public long getPid() {
    return pId;
}
}
```

my JPA Provider is :

```
public class JPAProvider {

    private static final EntityManagerFactory     entityManagerFactory;//instate of session for connect to database
    static{
        entityManagerFactory  = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyConnection");
    }

    public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
        return entityManagerFactory;
   }
}
```

PersonManager class is :

```
public class PersonManager {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManager entityManager = JPAProvider.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        entityTransaction.begin();

        Person person = new Person("midas" , "midas123" , "aaaaa@gmail.com", "female" ,"female-user.png" );
        Pictures pictures = new Pictures("aaa" , "akflkkglhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh" ,2);
        Pictures pictures2 = new Pictures("nnbnbn" , "affddAlllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll" ,5);
        List<Pictures> picturesList =new ArrayList<Pictures>();
        picturesList.add(pictures);
        picturesList.add(pictures2);
        person.setPicturesList(picturesList);

        entityManager.persist(person);
        entityTransaction.commit();
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

and persistence.xml :

```
<persistence-unit name="MyConnection" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="midas"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="midas123"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
        <property name="show_sql" value="true"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I used the following libraries :

1)hibernate-enverc-4.2.0.final

2)hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1-final.jar

3)tomcat library

my JDK version = 1.8.0-172

my IDE = IntellyJ Idea

I use Oracle 11g .

I tried to solve the problem by solving similar questions, but I could not . 
for example I checked the following topics  that were more similar to my problem :

[[Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource : Invocation of init method failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058001/error-creating-bean-with-name-entitymanagerfactory-defined-in-class-path-resou][1])

[[Getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33210860/getting-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-exceptionininitializererror-excepti][2])

Additional explanation: No tables have been created in the database so far.

Comment: Is the schema already created on the database?

Comment: @MichaelWiles   No ، Not made.

Comment: In passing, I think you should not build the EntityManagerFactory in a static initializer. Its initialization is very susceptible to fail, so putting it here guarantees that you cannot deal with its failing should it happen. The initialization belongs some place else.

Comment: @ArthurNoseda  I tested the same program in the same way and it runs correctly. Of course, that program was just a training example for the JPA.

Comment: looks like column  `UID`  is not present can you change `hm2ddl` property to   `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>` and try

Comment: @NawnitSen This solution did not solve the problem

Comment: still same error? did it create the query while starting the application?

Comment: @NawnitSen Yes it is . I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: @farzane i mean you have "showsql" as "true" ,so when you restarted the application did u see the ddl  query generated?and if yes what was the query which got got generated for USER table?

Comment: @NawnitSen No, no queries are displayed in the output.

Comment: @NawnitSen The error section was updated in the question.

Comment: @farzane  ideally ddl query should be generated and shown in console log .i don't know why it not showing . I have posted solution in answer try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like problem is with `@JoinColumn(name = "FK_PERSON",referencedColumnName = "UID")`
**referencedColumnName** attribute points to the related column in asociated/referenced entity, i.e. column name of the primary key. By default it is primary key of associated entity. You are not required to fill the **referencedColumnName** if the referenced entity has single column as PK, because there is no doubt what column it references (i.e. primary key column of associated entity).
change that line to `@JoinColumn(name = "FK_PERSON")` it should work.

**For more info about referencedColumnName refer to** "[What is referencedColumnName used for in JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244569/what-is-referencedcolumnname-used-for-in-jpa)"

Comment: Thanks so much for your follow up and help .
This error seems to be fixed , but I encountered another error :(

Comment: if you find my answer helpful please mark it is accepted.:) BTW what is another error that you are getting?

Comment: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction--->Caused by:javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement--->Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement--->Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: it says table doesnt exist...just check in the db if that particular table exist or not

Comment: No, there is not. USERS table and table of PICTURES are not created in the database.

Comment: either create it manually or  by "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"  property

Comment: I created my table by sql plus and run program . program was run correctly. 
tank you Nawinit Sen :)